# How to include average of digits in number in my code?

Tags: c

I don't understand how to include average of digits in my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, s;
    printf("Enter number : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    s = 0;
    while (n > 0)  {
        s += n%10;
        n /= 10;
    }
    printf("Sum of digit : %d\n",s);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, s,i=0;
    printf("Enter number : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    s = 0;
    while (n > 0)  
    {
        s += n%10;
        n /= 10;
        i++;
    }
    printf("Sum of digit : %d\n",s);
    if(i!=0)
        printf("Average is %f\n",(float)s/i);
    else
        printf("Average is Undefined\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is helps a lot!

Comment: In the edge case, average is not 0 but undefined (1 / 0). `printf("Average is UNDEFINED");`

Comment: @Ardent Coder     Thank for your suggestion, i updated that.

Comment: @Srilakshmikanthan No worries, I'll upvote your answer and get you to 1K ;) However, there is still some scope of improvement. You could have added some explanation like what was the OP missing, the purpose of the new variables you introduced (it could have been named better), etc.